# Xamarin build error on TFS Build Server

Tags: android, tfs, xamarin, msbuild

We have a continuous integration build that builds multiple project types including WCF, WPF, class libraries etc., but also includes a few Xamarin Android projects.

Xamarin and the Android SDK is installed on the build server and we can get a successful build.  But 20% of the time the build fails with the following message.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (1462):
>   The "CopyMdbFiles" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.IOException:
>   The process cannot access the file
>   'F:\Builds\xxxx\xxxx.dll.mdb'
>   because it is being used by another process.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.HashFile(String filename, HashAlgorithm
>   hashAlg)    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.HashFile(String filename)
>   at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.CopyIfChanged(String source, String
>   destination)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.CopyMdbFiles.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext()

The build error can just disappear on the subsequent build with no change to the server or related code.

We also get this error from time to time.  Same as above, can just disappear with no change to the build server or related code.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (1871):
>   "java.exe" exited with code 2.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: What's the version of Xamarin you use? Looks like a Xamarin issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32976/updating-xamarin-broke-the-build-process-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-appname-dll-mdb

Comment: We're using 4.0.0.1697.  I could try upgrading to the latest but not seeing anything promising in the release notes.  I have made one change to the build environment, but it's too early to tell if it's resolved it.  We normally have 2 build agents running the builds in parallel.  I've disabled one of the agents and we're monitoring it now.

Comment: Build just failed with the "java.exe" exited with code error :(

Comment: I have upgraded to 4.0.0.1717.

Comment: Is there any details error message when jave.exe exited with code 2?

Comment: There's the following message from the build log.                           _CompileToDalvik: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\\bin\java.exe .... trouble writing output: Too many method references: 94325; max is 65536.
         You may try using --multi-dex option.

Comment: For jave exited with code issue, refer to this article from Android for details: [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: Thanks, we've made the change and we'll monitor for any failures.

Comment: Thanks @Eddie - MSFT for your help, we've a few days now without the build error.  We added selected multi dex option to the Xamarin project as suggested in the article you provided.  However, this broke the build until we moved our android SDK location to a path without a space.

Comment: To resolve the first build error we followed the advise provided in this [article](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/10439/#Comment_10439).